# CSS relative positioning

Tags: css, positioning

First of all, please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nK0de/JTBD8/2/). The gif image and the text is positioned exactly how I need them right now. But when I drag the pane and re-size it, the gif image's position changes. I want the gif image to stay on top of the 'Loading' text centered even when you resize the window. How can I do this? I tried using the `position: relative` but my CSS knowledge is almost at the bottom. Can anyone lend me some help on this please?

Thanks very much.

sidenote : The fiddle provided above is originally from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7901705/1077789). Thanks to [Robert Koritnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75642/robert-koritnik) for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about moving the `<img>` inside the `<div>` and using negative positioning to move it above the `Loading...` text?

#### HTML

```
This is some content
<div id="blocker">
<div>Loading...<img src="http://www.socialups.com/static/images/fbinventory/ajax_loader.gif"></div>
</div>

<button>click</button>
```

#### CSS

```
div#blocker {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: .5;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: auto;
}

div#blocker div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 5em;
    height: 2em;
    margin: -1em 0 0 -2.5em;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div#blocker img {
    position: relative;
    top: -55px;
    left: 15%;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("blocker").style.display = 'none';
}, 3000);
```

And as your [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDe6k/1/) also.

Comment: One little thing, How can I do the same thing **without** using jQuery. I'm having trouble with the `CSS Selectors`. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nK0de/KDe6k/)

Comment: You nearly have it! It's just that the CSS selectors are backwards. You need `div#blocker div` and `div#blocker img`. Also note that these have nothing to do with jQuery. In your fiddle you have intentionally not loaded jQuery but that is causing a problem since your JavaScript is calling the jQuery `.hide()` method. Also note that `.hide()` can only be called on a jQuery object and document.getElementId does not return a jQuery object. I have updated my answer with the complete jQuery-free solution

Comment: thank you very much. I even posted another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8687429/1077789) 'cause I thought you wouldn't see my last comment. :) anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that one of your elements is positioned relatively and the other is absolute. One is relative to it's parent container, the other is relative to the page. So when the page is resized, the bounding box that governs their scaling is proportionate to different metrics.