# CSS - incorrect using of Selectors?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

This is the code I have right now with jQuery. [1.fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nK0de/JTBD8/5/) What I want is to create the same scenario **without** jQuery. This is where I ended up. [2. fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nK0de/KDe6k/)
Can anyone point out what I have done wrong here?? (As far as I can think of, my problem is with the `CSS Selectors`)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is no `.hide()` method in HTML. To hide an element, set the `display` style to `none`.

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    document.getElementById("blocker").style.display = "none";
}, 3000);
```

Also, the original CSS can work without jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Try below. Don't use `hide()` in native javascript.

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    document.getElementById("blockid").style.display = "none";
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no function hide() in native javascript. Replace the `hide()` function with following line.

```
    document.getElementById("blocker").style.display = 'none';
```